# Laravel join returns only the first row of joined table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am using latest Laravel and this is my query:

```
return DB::table('cars')
    ->join('photos', 'cars.id', '=', 'photos.car_id')
    ->select('photos.img')
    ->get();
```

Car model has many photos and Photo model belongs to Car, but I think for this query, it doesn't matter.

It returns all the cars, but all with one photo. There are many photos for each car.

Comment: `'cars.id', '=', 'photos.id'` should probably be something like `'cars.id', '=', 'photos.car_id'`. Better yet, use a proper Laravel relationship, so you can just do `return Car::with('photos')->get()`.

Comment: Oh, sry it is, will edit the question.

Comment: what you are getting for left join?

Comment: @gdfgdfg it seems there's nothing wrong with your query. Have to see the data of both tables, so can you post a screenshot of your `cars` and `photos` table?

Comment: If I use `with` it returns same car rows with many photos and parent id like this: `photos:[{img: 'img url', id: 'parent id'}]`. With join it returns flat  collection with `img: 'url to img'`